# Does List.Remove find the exact object or just a similar object?

Tags: c#, list

I was looking through MSDN and it's not really clear.  I have a list and I need to make sure that the T object that gets removed is the exact one that I want removed otherwise I want the method to return something to indicate false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If type T implements the IEquatable generic interface, the equality comparer is the Equals method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality comparer is Object.Equals.

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically what that means is that if your object does on implement the IEquality interface it will remove the instance you pass to the remove method if it's in the list. By instance I mean the exact object - what you pass to remove is pointing to the same memory location as an entry in the list

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the object and the `Equals` method implemented by the object.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

You may in some cases have to override `Equals` to ensure you get the result you expect.